# How @Repository and @Autowired work in spring boot Dao and Service Layer?

Tags: java, spring-boot

## Below is a my sample Dao and Service Layer.

All are in different Packages.
I am using spring-boot 1.4.
How an autowired Dao interface call DaoImpl methods directly?
In java, an interface can refer to child object but iterface.childMethod() is not possible.
What i am thinking is , since i am doing dependency injection, somehow i am receiving an object of daoImpl in service layer.
Can anyone explain the whole concept of what is happening?

**ISocietyAccountMasterDao**

```
public interface ISocietyAccountMasterDao extends IGenericRepository<SocietyAccountMaster> {

    List<SocietyAccountMaster> getAllSocietyAccounts(String societyId, Long accountTypeId);

}
```

**SocietyAccountMasterDaoImpl**

```
public class SocietyAccountMasterDaoImpl extends AbstractDao<String, SocietyAccountMaster>
        implements ISocietyAccountMasterDao {

    private final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggingAspect.MANUAL);

    @Override
    public List<SocietyAccountMaster> getAllSocietyAccounts(String societyId, Long accountTypeId) {
        Criteria cr = getEntityCriteria();
        try {
            cr.add(Restrictions.eq("societyId", societyId));
            if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(accountTypeId)) {
                cr.add(Restrictions.eq("accountType.id", accountTypeId));
            }
            return cr.list();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error While Society Accounts", e);
            throw new BindException(BindStatus.FAILURE, BindStatus.FAILURE_MSG);
        }
    }
```

**ISocietyAccountingService**

```
public interface ISocietyAccountingService {
    List<SocietyAccountMasterDto> getAllSocietyAccounts(String societyId);
}
```

**SocietyAccountingServiceImpl**

```
@Service("societyAccountingService")
@Transactional
public class SocietyAccountingServiceImpl implements ISocietyAccountingService {

@Override
    public List<SocietyAccountMasterDto> getAllSocietyAccounts(String societyId) {
        List<SocietyAccountMasterDto> responses = new ArrayList<SocietyAccountMasterDto>();
        List<SocietyAccountMaster> dbSocietyAccountMasters = societyAccountMasterDao.getAllSocietyAccounts(societyId,
                null);
        for (SocietyAccountMaster dbSocietyAccountMaster : dbSocietyAccountMasters) {
            SocietyAccountMasterDto response = new SocietyAccountMasterDto();
            response.setNickName(dbSocietyAccountMaster.getNickName());
            response.setBankName(dbSocietyAccountMaster.getBankName());
            response.setBalance(dbSocietyAccountMaster.getBalance());
            responses.add(response);
        }
        return responses;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Component` - Indicates a bean is an auto scan component. It means spring will search for bean with beanName, when it is injected as autowire.

`@Repository` -  Indicates DAO component in the persistence layer available as auto-scan component.

If see implements of `@Repository` annonation as shown below:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE}) 
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME) 
@Documented 
@Component
public @interface Repository {

    /**
     * The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name,
     * to be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.
     * @return the suggested component name, if any
     */
    String value() default "";

}
```

This annotation class is annotated with `@Component`, which makes it available for auto-wiring. this is reason with DAO impl is available to Service via auto-wiring since Spring auto-detecting it.